# "visibility: hidden" style being applied to inputTextArea in VF

Tags: visualforce

I have a very simple page that is constructed as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Custom_Object__c" extensions="ObjectController">
    <apex:form>
         <apex:inputfield value="{!customObject.Description__c}"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

yet when I try to load this page, this is what the output of the field looks like in the markup

```
<textarea id="j_id0:j_id2:j_id210:j_id211:j_id213:j_id214:textAreaDelegate_Description__c" name="j_id0:j_id2:j_id210:j_id211:j_id213:j_id214:textAreaDelegate_Description__c" rows="25" style="visibility: hidden;">abcabc</textarea>
```

as you can see there is a "visibility: hidden" style being applied which hides the text area (also, the field should be of type Rich Text but for some reason it's appearing as a textarea). The field level security is editable by all users too, so that can't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To display richTextArea use `<apex:inputtextarea`> with `richtext="true"`

```
<apex:inputtextarea 
label="RichText" 
id="rt" 
richtext="true" 
value="{!customObject.Description__c}" 
cols="100" 
rows="10"/>
```